# Is there a way to register an onclick event handler on elements within an SVG image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'd like to load an SVG image within a HTML5 page and make it's components clickable. If the user moves the mouse over the shapes presented by the SVG an `onclick` event should perform some action. The goal is to enable the user to either click on parts of the SVG image or to click on data rows provided in a table below that SVG.

All SVG components are `g` elements that have a `text` element which in turn has text content that could be used as an ID for later on distinguishing the individual components.

SVG-Example (abbreviated by having only a single `g`-component and the text "abc"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="232pt" height="260pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 231.69 260.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <g class="node">
        <ellipse fill="#008000" stroke="#ffffff" cx="61.545" cy="-90" rx="46.2923" ry="18"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="61.545" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">abc</text>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Is there a way to use JQuery (or some other JavaScript library or pure JavaScript code) to register `onclick` event handlers on these `g` elements? And if so how can you do it?

Comment: How are you including the SVG into the html page? Is it simply inline in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added an ID to the `g` element, and with simple jQuery I could manage to get the `onClick` event.

```
<svg width="232pt" height="260pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 231.69 260.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <g class="node" id="myId">
        <ellipse fill="#008000" stroke="#ffffff" cx="61.545" cy="-90" rx="46.2923" ry="18"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="61.545" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">abc</text>
    </g>
</svg>

$("#myId").on("click", function() { ... });
```

You can use whatever you want.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oc6zm1by/

Comment: Wow. So you're suggesting inlining the SVG and then using classic JQuery selectors?

Comment: @RegisMay jquery + SVG generally leads to much pain.

Comment: If you are loading the SVG via an `<img>` or `background-image`, then the answer is no. You cannot attach events to individual SVG elements in that case. You need to inline the SVG, or embed using an `<object>`.

Comment: I can embed it. Perfect! Thank you for your assistance.